# Issues with deploying Flask app to Google App Engine - Error Messages

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm very new to Cloud services and am currently working on a personal project to deploy a chatbot web application on Google App Engine. When I run the command `gcloud app deploy` on the Cloud Shell Terminal, I keep getting the following Error Messages:

```
Step #1: ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Python==3.7.3 (from -r requirements.txt (line 3)) (from versions: none)
Step #1: ERROR: No matching distribution found for Python==3.7.3 (from -r requirements.txt (line 3))
Step #1: WARNING: You are using pip version 20.2.2; however, version 21.3.1 is available.
Step #1: You should consider upgrading via the '/env/bin/python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
Step #1: The command '/bin/sh -c pip install -r requirements.txt' returned a non-zero code: 1
Finished Step #1
ERROR
ERROR: build step 1 "gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker@sha256:xxxx" failed: step exited with non-zero status: 1
```

This is what is in my requirements.txt file:

```
Flask==1.1.2
Werkzeug==1.0.1
Python==3.7.3
gunicorn==20.0.4
```

And this is what's in my app.yaml:

```
runtime: python
env: flex
runtime_config:
        python_version: 3

api_version: 1
threadsafe: true
entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT main:app
```

Not sure what to make of these errors, as I've already tried installing the latest version of pip and Python 3.7.3.

Comment: You shouldn't mention python in the `requirements.txt`, it is meant only to keep all the external dependencies that are installed using pip. So, just remove `Python==3.7.3` from the requirements file.

Answer (score 0):

Removing Python==3.7.3 should solve your issue.

You can also use this command instead of writing it yourself to avoid any error `pip install -r requirements.txt`. You can get more information on this in [installing dependencies locally](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/specifying-dependencies#installing_dependencies_locally).